# time out expired issue in lambda method for contains

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have this code:

```
 string[] splits = keyword.Split(' ');

        var fproducts = (from products in db.tbl_Product
                         where splits.Any(item => products.Prod_Name_Fa.Contains(item) ||
                    products.shortDesc.Contains(item) || products.Prod_Code.Contains(item))
                         select products).Distinct();
```

if splits have 2 or 3 words it works but when I put 5 words in that I get time out expired error,

Is there any other solution to search an array in a field ?

**Update:**

this is the sql output :

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Register_Date] AS [Register_Date], 
    [Extent1].[tbl_VATID] AS [tbl_VATID], 
    [Extent1].[Prod_Name_Fa] AS [Prod_Name_Fa], 
    [Extent1].[Prod_Code] AS [Prod_Code], 
    [Extent1].[Prod_Description_Fa] AS [Prod_Description_Fa], 
    [Extent1].[Prod_Description_En] AS [Prod_Description_En], 
    [Extent1].[Prod_How_To_Use] AS [Prod_How_To_Use], 
    [Extent1].[Prod_Keywords] AS [Prod_Keywords], 
    [Extent1].[Prod_Model] AS [Prod_Model], 
    [Extent1].[User_Rating] AS [User_Rating], 
    [Extent1].[Admin_Rating] AS [Admin_Rating], 
    [Extent1].[Seen_Counter] AS [Seen_Counter], 
    [Extent1].[Is_Ashantyvn_Salable] AS [Is_Ashantyvn_Salable], 
    [Extent1].[shortDesc] AS [shortDesc], 
    [Extent1].[basePrice] AS [basePrice], 
    [Extent1].[Discount] AS [Discount], 
    [Extent1].[discountDateFrom] AS [discountDateFrom], 
    [Extent1].[discountDateTo] AS [discountDateTo], 
    [Extent1].[Sex] AS [Sex], 
    [Extent1].[Publish] AS [Publish], 
    [Extent1].[basePic] AS [basePic], 
    [Extent1].[suggestDate] AS [suggestDate], 
    [Extent1].[isSuggest] AS [isSuggest], 
    [Extent1].[homesuggestDate] AS [homesuggestDate], 
    [Extent1].[homeisSuggest] AS [homeisSuggest], 
    [Extent1].[suggestNum] AS [suggestNum], 
    [Extent1].[tagOrder] AS [tagOrder]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_Product] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            N'رژ' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            N'لب' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            N'دو' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            N'رنگ' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            N'لوویو' AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable5]) AS [UnionAll4]
        WHERE (( CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll4].[C1], [Extent1].[Prod_Name_Fa]) AS int)) > 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll4].[C1], [Extent1].[shortDesc]) AS int)) > 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll4].[C1], [Extent1].[Prod_Code]) AS int)) > 0)
    )}
```

Comment: How many records in tbl_Product?  Can you see the SQL that is generated as a result?

Comment: @DStanley 1317 records, no, How can I see ?

Comment: @SepehrEstaki: When debugging, check out the value of `fproducts.ToString()`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior look at my update please.

Comment: @SepehrEstaki: It doesn't look too horrible. How many total records do you have in that table? You can use SQL Server Management Studio to see how long this query would take outside of Entity Framework, and analyze the execution plan to see why. Or you can just try applying my suggested answer and see if that makes things better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For best performance, I have to select just ID of the model not all, 
it should be like this :

```
 string[] splits = keyword.Split(' ');

        var fproducts = (from products in db.tbl_Product
                         where splits.Any(item => products.Prod_Name_Fa.Contains(item) ||
                    products.shortDesc.Contains(item) || products.Prod_Code.Contains(item))
                         select products.ID).Distinct();
```

**products.ID**

and then select the records when equals these IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what mechanism Entity Framework is using to translate your query, but it's likely that you're getting something unnecessarily complicated. Try composing your own intersection of queries returning results for each keyword, like so:

```
string[] splits = keyword.Split(' ');
if(!splits.Any())
    return db.tbl_Product; // or something
var queries = splits
    .Select(item => db.tbl_Product
        .Where(product => product.Prod_Name_Fa.Contains(item)  ||
                product.shortDesc.Contains(item) || 
                product.Prod_Code.Contains(item))));
return items.Aggregate((q1, q2) => q1.Union(q2));
```